# product images created with contentful not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contentful

I'm working on shopping cart and using `contentful` to create my products in it.

For some reason, if I opened my page using live server in visual studio code , images will appear and everything is fine but if I tried opening it manually (double clicking the html file) all product images will disappear, but my other content like price and title is still there and working.

I would've shared my code but don't know which part shall I share ?

```
  try {
    // let result = await fetch("products.json");
    // let data = await result.json();
    let contentful = await client.getEntries({
      content_type: "vantProducts"
    });
    console.log(contentful.items);

    let products = contentful.items;
    products = products.map(item => {
      const { title, price } = item.fields;
      const { id } = item.sys;
      const image = item.fields.image.fields.file.url;
      return { title, price, id, image };
    });

    return products;
  }
```

Comment: We just want to see a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan i posted the code that links my data with contentful i don't know if that's enough to see the problem i'm having